# Type incompatibility error with no apparent incompatibility

Tags: typescript

I have an "options" tuple `[string,function]` that provides a `string` that identifies a check and a `function` on which that check is to be executed.
(There is no way to figure out the check to perform out of an analysis of the function, so that the actual check has to be instructed via that string.)
In the code I wrote to implement this, it seems to me that the types of the checks and the types of the ckeched functions will not mismatch.
But TypeScript disagrees and gives me an incompatibility error.

```
// tsconfig.json
// {"compilerOptions": {"noImplicitAny": true}};

// Types and interfaces

interface f1_sig { (x:string): string }
interface f2_sig { (x:number): number }

interface f1Chk_sig { (f1:f1_sig): boolean }
interface f2Chk_sig { (f2:f2_sig): boolean }

type options_type = 
  ['f1',f1_sig] | 
  ['f2',f2_sig] ;

interface optionsDictionary_indexer {
  f1: f1Chk_sig;
  f2: f2Chk_sig;
}

// Implementations

const f1: f1_sig = x => x;
const f2: f2_sig = x => x;
const f1Chk: f1Chk_sig = f => f('0')?true:false;
const f2Chk: f2Chk_sig = f => f( 0 )?true:false;

const optionsDictionary: optionsDictionary_indexer = {
  f1: f1Chk,
  f2: f2Chk
};

// Alternative 1
const optionsExtractor_1:
  (options: options_type) => boolean
  =
options => 
  optionsDictionary[options[0]](options[1])
  // Error in the text editor: 'f1Chk | f2Chk' has no compatible call signatures

// Alternative 2
const optionsExtractor_2:
  (options: options_type) => boolean
  =
options =>
  options[0]==='f1' ? f1Chk(options[1]) :
  options[0]==='f2' ? f2Chk(options[1]) : false;
  // Error in the text editor: Argument of type 'f1Chk | f2Chk' is not assignable to parameter of type f2_sig
```

How can I possible mix the types? Where am I wrong? If I'm not wrong, can anybody come up with a no-hack way to relieve TypeScript of the fear of `f1Chk` being called with `f2`, or `f2Chk` with `f1`?

Comment: Don't think you will get out of this without a type assertion. The compiler can't really follow the relation between `optionsDictionary[options[0]]` and `options[1]` even if it's apparent to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things going on here.

Your "Alternative 1" is running into an issue that I've calling "correlated types", where you have an expression that isn't seen to be valid on a union type, even though it is valid for each of the possible narrowings of that union.  There isn't currently a great solution in TypeScript for it.  I've [suggested](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) something that would let you force the compiler to walk through the possible narrowings, but there's little chance it will get implemented.  Maybe someday control flow analysis will be sophisticated enough for this to work.  But for now, the only workarounds I know of are type assertions or redundant code.

Your "Alternative 2" is the redundant code I'm talking about.  But it still doesn't work!   It's because of an [outstanding bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) where control flow analysis on a property doesn't work when you use bracket notation to [access the property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors). Your code would not error if you use dot notation to access the tuple properties... but unfortunately there is no way to use dot notation for a numeric index.  You could change the code to use something instead of a tuple, like this:

```
type options_type =
  {zero: 'f1', one: f1_sig} |
  {zero: 'f2', one: f2_sig};

// Alternative 2, works now
const optionsExtractor_2:
  (options: options_type) => boolean
  =
  options =>
    options.zero === 'f1' ? f1Chk(options.one) :
      options.zero === 'f2' ? f2Chk(options.one) : false;
```

But probably you should just use a type assertion, which is the recommended approach when you are more clever than the compiler:

```
interface fEitherChk_sig { (f12: f1_sig | f2_sig): boolean }
// Alternative 1
const optionsExtractor_1:
  (options: options_type) => boolean
  =
  options =>
    (optionsDictionary[options[0]] as fEitherChk_sig)(options[1])
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!